# Public folder not compiling with react/webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, compilation, public

Not sure where I'm going wrong, or if I have a dev dependency missing.  But basically, I am setting up a react app from scratch, where I want my **assets (images and SCSS), index.html ** and **app.js** ,to be served in a **"public"** folder.

Folder structure should be something like this:

```
ReactApplication:
- config
- controllers
- lib
- models
- node_modules
- public
- src:
     - assets:
             - images
             - scss
     - components
     - app.js
     - index.html
- test
.bablerc
index.js
nodemon.json
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

I have setup my webpack file, index.json and everything else listed above.  However, NO assets/app.js are being compiled in the **public** folder.

I have no idea why not. My app works 100% fine and running on node/in the browser.  I get no errors, but I'm expecting files to appear/be compiled in the public folder.

What am I missing?

I've copy and pasted this project from an existing one. So could it be I need to reinstall a dependency?

Here's my webpack file:

```
const path = require('path');
console.log('path', path);
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpack = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'src/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpack = new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { from: './src/assets', to: 'assets' }
]);

const HotModuleReplcement = new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin();

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('public'),
    filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      { test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/, loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000' },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
      { test: /\.jpe?g(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpeg' },
      { test: /\.gif(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif' },
      { test: /\.png(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png' }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: ['src'],
    watchContentBase: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    port: 8000,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:4000', 
        secure: false
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [HotModuleReplcement, HtmlWebpack, CopyWebpack]
};
```

Here's my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// mongoose.plugin(require('mongoose-unique-validator'));
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
const router = require('./config/router');
const errorHandler = require('./lib/errorHandler');

const { dbURI, port } = require('./config/environment');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));

mongoose.connect(dbURI);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', router);
app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/public/index.html`));

app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Aye aye captain, pulling into port ${port}`));

module.exports = app;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-webpack-setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:client": "webpack-dev-server",
    "start:server": "nodemon",
    "test:server": "nyc mocha \"test/server/**/*_spec.js\" --require \"test/server/spec_helper\" --recursive --exit",
    "test:client": "mocha --require ignore-styles test/client/helper \"test/client/**/*_test.js\" --recursive --exit",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "start": "yarn build && node index"
  },
  "author": "Students",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.8",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "jsdom": "^11.7.0",
    "mocha": "^5.0.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "nyc": "^11.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "bulma": "^0.6.2",
    "filestack-js": "^0.11.2",
    "filestack-react": "^1.3.9",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.1",
    "loadash": "^1.0.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.13",
    "promises": "^0.2.5",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-messages": "^1.3.2",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-timestamp": "^4.4.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you triggering a compilation/build?

Comment: @ChrisB. - Good question, I have just included my package.json to the above.  The only thing I can think, is that my dependencies maybe out of date/clashing with each other. Causing this compilation not to work....  Like a versioning issue maybe...  As everything seems to be correct...  When I run client and server... no errors are returned..

Comment: I mean, are you running ```webpack``` or ```npm run build```/```yarn build```?

Comment: @ChrisB. I'm running nodemon and webpack, through yarn:

    "start:server": "nodemon",
    "start:client": "webpack-dev-server",

Comment: No output files are generated unless the ```webpack``` command is run. Only running the dev server will store the bundle in memory, but not generate a static file. Try using ```yarn build``` and see if the files show up.